How to filter column headers in Excel using a data dictionary in a separate file?
I have two files: a file to fill out with reporting data (composed of multiple sheets/flats) and a data dictionary for the columns in that file. I can delete columns from the reporting data file but not the header rows.
The reporting data template is formatted like so, where the rows below these three are blank and would be filled out for each project/grantee (there are hundreds of columns):



Column Header
Program (DE001)
Recipient (DE002)
Transaction Identifier - Grantee (DE005)
Project Capacity (DE074)




Data Type
Picklist
String
String
Number


Picklist Options
Not applicable
Not applicable
Not applicable
Not applicable



The data dictionary is formatted like so, with one row for each column header:



Data Element
Field Name
Definition
Data Type
Flat File Name
Applicability




DE001
Program
This field identifies the program
Picklist
0-Award
0-All


DE002
Recipient
This field identifies the prime recipient
String
0-Award
0-All


DE005
Transaction Identifier - Grantee
This field contains a value to uniquely identify the grantee
String
0-Award
0-All


DE074
Project Capacity
This field is total capacity of the project
Number
1-Project
2-Project



As an example, DE074 is not applicable for me because "Applicability" is "2-Project" instead of "0-All". Is there a way to only keep columns in the reporting file where the "Applicability" in the data dictionary is "0-All"? I need to return it with the same header rows but it's ok if I remove columns because of the way their machine reads these templates.
I did a vlookup row beneath picklist options that pulls in the "Applicability" info but there doesn't seem to be a way to just select every column with "2-Project" in that row and delete the whole column. I could do a transpose -> convert to table -> filter -> transpose again, but there are many sheets and I would have to do that for each sheet. If that's the best way, I'll just do that, but it feels like there must be a simpler way.

For clarity, you're asking to display rows that do not contain "2-Project" in any column for each sheet?  To actually rows().delete would need VBA, so wanting to make sure you're not requesting a script, which is out of scope for SO.

I was hoping to delete them. I just figured out that I could Find all "2-Project", select them all in the Find panel/window, and then use the Delete button in the menu bar to Delete Columns. Still have to go sheet by sheet but it's quicker than transposing and filtering a table.
